# Finding a whole string using grep

Tags: bash, scripting, grep, flags

I'm trying to find whole strings using grep. I am familiar with -w flag, but it gives me hard time since it refers a dot as a delimiter.

For example, I have a file named "a.txt" and a directory names a in some directory, this is what happens:

```
> ls | grep -w a
a
a.txt
```

What I want it to find is only "a" and that's it.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a single `a` on a line, use

```
grep '^a$'
```

If you only take whitespace as the delimiter, use

```
grep '\([[:space:]]\|^\)a\([[:space:]]\|$\)'
```

(i.e. whitespace or beginning of the line, a, whitespace or end of the line).

Answer (score 2):

use the x optin of grep

```
 ls | grep -x a
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach too would be:

```
grep '^[[:space:]]*a[[:space:]]*$'
```

Something more friendly with variables is by use of awk. It would not interpret input pattern as regex.

```
awk -v v="$var" '{ sub(/^[[:space:]]*/, ""); sub(/[[:space:]]*$/, ""); }; $0 == v;'
```